# Superscript React-Native text

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, exponent, superscript

In my React-Native app I would like to add superscript(exponent) in text.

For example,

I have this text: Here's a new product called test^123. This product can do ...

So in this example ^123 is the superscript(exponent)

I have try a lot of thing but I can not fix the problem because every time the text start on another line.

Do anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can insert the unicode value of the superscript characters you require. See the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) for which unicode values to use. To insert these values into the text you wish to display, use the format \uXXXX in the string you wish to display. In your given example the string would be 'test\u00B9\u00B2\u00B3'.

If you need to build these superscript strings dynamically you will need a simple mapping function that receives the standard digits and returns the unicode values.

If you prefer to be more literal in your code, you can also insert the unicode characters right there in the string - provided your file is encoded as UTF-8. For this, you can copy the characters from another source or see [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183045/how-can-i-type-unicode-characters-without-using-the-mouse), for example. A similar mapping function could be made for this approach too.

Comment: Simple and effective solution +1

Comment: if i could i will give to this solution +30 points. There a lot of really bad solutions out there and there is a shame that this post isn't the first result on google. 

GJ man, awesome solution.

Comment: This is such a stupid problem for a framework not to solve but interesting solution you've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *very hacky* solution, but can approximate English fairly well:

```js
function convertStringToSuperscript(str: string) {
  // more options exist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts
  const superscriptUpperCase = ['ᴬ', 'ᴮ', 'ᶜ', 'ᴰ', 'ᴱ', 'ᴭ', 'ᴳ', 'ᴴ', 'ᴵ', 'ᴶ', 'ᴷ', 'ᴸ', 'ᴹ', 'ᴺ', 'ᴼ', 'ᴾ', 'ᶞ', 'ᴿ', 'ˢ', 'ᵀ', 'ᵁ', 'ᵛ', 'ᵂ', 'ᵡ', 'ᵞ', 'ᶻ'];
  const superscriptLowerCase = ['ᵃ', 'ᵇ', 'ᶜ', 'ᵈ', 'ᵉ', 'ᶠ', 'ᵍ', 'ʰ', 'ⁱ', 'ʲ', 'ᵏ', 'ˡ', 'ᵐ', 'ⁿ', 'ᵒ', 'ᵖ', 'ᶞ', 'ʳ', 'ˢ', 'ᵗ', 'ᵘ', 'ᵛ', 'ʷ', 'ˣ', 'ʸ', 'ᶻ'];
  const isLowerCase = (code: number) => code >= 97 && code <= 122   // A:65 - Z:90
  const isUpperCase = (code: number) => code >= 65 && code <= 90    // a:95 - z:122
  const toSuperscript = (char: string): string => {
    const code = char.charCodeAt(0)
    if (isLowerCase(code)) return superscriptLowerCase[code - 97]
    if (isUpperCase(code)) return superscriptUpperCase[code - 65]
    // if not in range return character as it was
    return char
  }
  // this part isn't very optimized
  return str.split("").map(toSuperscript).join("")
}
```